# Mongo incorrectly inserts nested array as indexed object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to insert a document that has nested arrays on it as value objects, but mongo converts the nested array into an indexed object.

```
    db.myCollection.insertMany([
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5e41974d65f219c3310f2b4f"),
        _class: "myClass",
        myFirstLevelArray: [
            {
                myNestedArray: [
                    {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        ]

    }]);
```

I expect that mongo stores the following object:

```
{
        _id: ObjectId("5e41974d65f219c3310f2b4f"),
        _class: "myClass",
        myFirstLevelArray: [
            {
                myNestedArray: [
                    {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
```

But what I get is:

```
   {
        _id: ObjectId("5e41974d65f219c3310f2b4f"),
        _class: "myClass",
        myFirstLevelArray: [
            {
                myNestedArray: {
                    '0': {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    },
                    '1': {
                        value: "value",
                        value2: "value2"
                    }                   
                }
            }
        ]

    }
```

I thought I might need to add the `$each` keyword or something like that, but it seems that they are not appropriate for insert statements. Is there something wrong with the statement? Do I need to put some kind of flag on it or is it some kind of bug?

Comment: I tried your `insertMany` method in the Mongo Shell. It works fine as expected when I query in the Mongo Shell. What _tool_ are you using to insert and query the collection?

Comment: I'm using jetbrains' Datagrip

Comment: It might be something to do with the tool you are using - maybe it just displays like that. Can you query the collection in Mongo Shell and see what it is.

Comment: That's the issue. I've tried using Robo3t and it worked too. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?